# React Component Not Being Populated even after updating state and executing forEach

Tags: reactjs, react-state, react-state-management

I want to fetch memes from the imgflip meme API, and even though I get to see the HTTP response in my console, the DOM is not getting populated, I tried everything.

```
export default class MemesContainer extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      memes: [],
    };
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    let req = await fetch("https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes");
    let res = await req.json();
    console.log(res.data.memes);
    await this.setState({ memes: res.data.memes });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container d-flex justify-content-center flex-wrap">
        {this.state.memes.map((e) => {
          <div className="card m-3" style={{ width: "18" + "rem" }}>
            <img src={e.url} className="card-img-top" alt="..." />
            <div className="card-body">
              <h5 className="card-title">{e.name}</h5>
            </div>
          </div>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ForEach` Doesn't return anything, it just executes the code. At this point you should use `Array.map` as it is meant to loop through array and transform it's values and return them.

```
export default class MemesContainer extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      memes: [],
    };
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    let req = await fetch("https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes");
    let res = await req.json();
    console.log(res.data.memes);
    await this.setState({ memes: res.data.memes });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container d-flex justify-content-center flex-wrap">
        {this.state.memes.map((e) => {
          return (
          <div className="card m-3" style={{ width: "18" + "rem" }}>
            <img src={e.url} className="card-img-top" alt="..." />
            <div className="card-body">
              <h5 className="card-title">{e.name}</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        )
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Still, it's not working! If I console log from inside the map(), it shows exactly what I want, but it is not populating the DOM.

Comment: I've made an edit to add `return`, make sure you copy-pasted the correct version of the answer.

Comment: It worked, thanks for letting me know that small mistake!

Comment: Make sure to mark your question as answered, if it did solved your problem.

Comment: Yes, I was just going to do that, but stackoverflow said that I can mark it answered after 6 minutes, anyways, it's now marked as answered, thanks!